# Autofac resolve class by specified constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class UserTaskChangesObserver : IObserver
{
    protected readonly IUserTaskChangesObservable UserTaskChangesObservable;
    protected readonly IUserAccountChangesObservable UserAccountChangesObservable;

    protected UserTaskChangesObserver(IUserTaskChangesObservable userTaskChangesObservable)
    {
        if (userTaskChangesObservable == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userTaskChangesObservable));
        }
        UserTaskChangesObservable = userTaskChangesObservable;
    }

    protected UserTaskChangesObserver(IUserAccountChangesObservable userAccountChangesObservable)
    {
        if (userAccountChangesObservable == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userAccountChangesObservable));
        }
        UserAccountChangesObservable = userAccountChangesObservable;
    }

    protected abstract void OnUserTaskChange(object sender, UserTaskEventArgs userTaskEventArgs);
    protected abstract void OnUserAccountChange(object sender, UserAccountEventArgs userTaskEventArgs);
}
```

Is it possible to say autofac which constructor I want to use during resolving my `RealClass` from context?
For example for the current service I want to call the first constructor:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserTaskService>().AsSelf().As<IUserTaskChangesObservable>()
     .OnActivated(args =>args.Context.Resolve<UserTaskChangesObserver>().Subscribe()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Why would you have class with the different constructors, seems to me like design smell.

Comment: Do you think would be it better if I create one more abstract Observer?

Comment: Two different constructors are clear indication that class doing more than it should do, dealing with `UserTask` and dealing with `UserAccount`. I think it would be better to separate these. That will also solve your `Autofac` problem.

Comment: I chose such design 'because some modifications with `UserAccount` entail `UserTask` changes. Specify, I need recalculate some `UserTask` fields if `UserAccount` property has been changed.

Comment: Having multiple constructors is [an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: @Steven tnx for article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two constructors isn't even a design smell, as @Lepijohnny points out it is **an anti-pattern**. [This article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) explains in detail why this is an anti-pattern and how to prevent this.

In your case it seems that your class has two responsibilities. The solution is to split it into two separate classes.